# Objective-C addObject seems to put object into all array indices

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to learn how to make simple classes.

So far I am not getting the results expected using addObject and my class.

Here is what I have:

In my view controller:

```
#import "onoffclass.h"
```

In its viewDidLoad:

```
  NSMutableArray *inTable;
  onoffclass *therec;
  onoffclass *readrec;
  inTable = [NSMutableArray array];
  therec = [[onoffclass alloc]init];
  readrec =  [[onoffclass alloc]init];
  for (int lop=0;lop<3;lop++){
     therec.parsedID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",lop];
     [inTable addObject:therec];
     NSLog(@"lop=%i  onoff.parsedID=%@",lop,therec.parsedID);
     for (int z=0;z<[inTable count];z++){
        readrec = inTable[z];
        NSLog(@"                            inTable[%i]  parsedID=%@",z,readrec.parsedID);
     }
  }
```

In my onoffclass.h:

```
@interface onoffclass : NSObject
    @property NSString *parsedID;
    @property NSString *parsedOn;
    @property NSString *parsedOff;
    @property NSString *parsedAdj;
    @property NSString *parsedRoom;
    @property NSString *parsedBuilding;
    @property NSString *parsedWho;
    @property NSString *parsedInfo;
    @property NSString *parsedBillable;

-(onoffclass*)initWithSomeString: (NSString*)blah AndSomeNum: (int)num;
-(NSString*)description;

@end
```

In my onoffclass.m:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "onoffclass.h"


@implementation onoffclass {
    NSString *_parsedID;
    NSString *_parsedOn;
    NSString *_parsedOff;
    NSString *_parsedAdj;
    NSString *_parsedRoom;
    NSString *_parsedBuilding;
    NSString *_parsedWho;
    NSString *_parsedInfo;
    NSString *_parsedBillable;
}

-(onoffclass*)initWithSomeString: (NSString*)blah AndSomeNum: (int)num {
    self = [super init];
    _parsedID = blah;
    _parsedOn = @"on";
    _parsedOff = @"off";
    _parsedAdj = @"adj";
    _parsedRoom = @"room";
    _parsedBuilding = @"building";
    _parsedWho = @"who";
    _parsedInfo = @"info";
    _parsedBillable = @"billable";
    return self;
}

-(NSString*)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", _parsedID];
}
@end
```

Here is the output:

```
 lop=0  onoff.parsedID=0
                             inTable[0]  parsedID=0
 lop=1  onoff.parsedID=1
                             inTable[0]  parsedID=1
                             inTable[1]  parsedID=1
 lop=2  onoff.parsedID=2
                             inTable[0]  parsedID=2
                             inTable[1]  parsedID=2
                             inTable[2]  parsedID=2
```

Why does it appears that addObject is updating all array indices and how do I fix this?

Thanks,
Dale

Comment: It's really difficult to read your code when you don't follow naming conventions.

Comment: ... and being parsimonious regarding space characters ;-)

Comment: Sorry, will work on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating **one** instance of `onoffclass` (by the way class names should start with a capital letter) then you are adding the same instance again and again in the loop. Since classes are reference types changing a property affects all occurrences of the same instance.

Solution is to put the line to create an instance **in** the loop

```
for (int lop = 0; lop < 3; lop++) {
   therec = [[onoffclass alloc] init];
   ...
```